# How do I create a node using inheritance?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like to create a node of the subclass `Unit` from `GameScene.swift`. The code can be executed, but you can't see a node.

I use the following code:

**GameScene.swift**

```
func setFirstUnit() {

    let myUnit = Unit(pHealthpoints: 10, pDamage: 5, pMovement: 1)
    myUnit.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(myUnit)
}
```

**Unit.swift**

```
class Unit: SKNode{

     var healthPoints: Int
     var damage: Int
     var movement: Int
     var texture: SKTexture
     let knightTexture = "KnightBlueV2"

     init(pHealthpoints: Int, pDamage: Int, pMovement: Int) {

        healthPoints = pHealthpoints
        damage = pDamage
        movement = pMovement

        texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: knightTexture)

        let unit = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        unit.zPosition = 4
        unit.setScale(1)

        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }

}
```

I would be very grateful for any answer.

Comment: I would print myUnit.position to see where it's been added.

Comment: `myUnit` seems to be in the middle, but unfortunately nothing can be seen there.

Comment: As long as I see in my old SpriteKit projects, I have never made a subclass of SKNode.  I have made a subclass of SKSpriteNode in some games.  So that may not be a way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I still had to change the code in a few places, but the problem was that I used `SKNode` instead of `SKSpriteNode`. If you want, you can write an answer, I'll mark it as right.

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from SKNode, which has no properties to display anything on the screen. That's why nothing shows up on the screen. If you want to see something on the screen, you need to inherit from SKSpriteNode or another node class with visible properties you can see on the screen.

There's a better solution for you than inheriting from one of the SpriteKit node classes. Instead of using inheritance, use composition. Give the Unit class a property of type SKSpriteNode and use that property to load textures, move the unit, and display the unit on the screen.

```
class Unit {
    sprite: SKSpriteNode
    // Rest of class here.
}
```